# How to replace an empty dict with a values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have the following:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : { 1 : {}},
    'b' : {1 : 3}
})
```

Which looks as :

```
    a  b
1  {}  3
```

And would like to be able to replace the `{}` with 0, or NaN, I'm not sure how to go about doing so though. I can't use `.replace` it seems

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : { 1 : {}},
    'b' : {1 : 3}
}).replace({ {} : 0})
```

Gives an error

Comment: Try `df = df.explode()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bool , when there is empty `dict` it will return `False`

```
df=df.where(df.astype(bool),0)

df
Out[26]: 
   a  b
1  0  3
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : { 1 : {}},
    'b' : {1 : 3}
})
df.applymap((lambda x: 0 if x == {} else x))
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : { 1 : {}},
    'b' : {1 : 3}
}).replace({ {} : 0})
```

cause error because `dict`'s keys must be hashable - `{}` is not. In such case you might use `pandas.DataFrame.replace` with two `list`s of equal length, following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : { 1 : {}},
    'b' : {1 : 3}
}).replace([{}],[0])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
1  0  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a dictionary is not hashable, `.replace` cannot act on in, however pandas has a function to handle iterables: `.explode`

```
print(df.explode('a'))
     a  b
1  NaN  3
```

It will still work if instead of being empty, the dictionary has 0-based consecutive integers keys (0, 1, n-1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : {1 : {0: 'row0', 1: 'row1'}},
    'b' : {1 : 3}
})

print(df.explode('a'))
      a  b
1  row0  3
1  row1  3
```

It will raise an exception if the dictionary is not empty or if the keys are not strictly continuous and 0-based (e.g. {2: val, 'string_key':val, -1:val} will cause explode to fail due to all three keys)